# ubuntu power button?

Tags: login, mac

i have a problem i want to change power button's location instead of right side i want it to be on left side is it possible i want to look it like mac please help me.

please if it is possible to change location of power button please help me

Comment: I take it you prefer MAC then, you could always buy one :)

Comment: my bro is buying but i love mine better :D